# Bind single control to multiple properties

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am currently developing a WPF Form and am trying to apply the MVVM pattern.
I got a datagrid, two Edit-controls and a Button. Simplified the code looks like this:

```
<syncfusion:SfDataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="TempGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding TempProfile}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTempSetpoint}">
</syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
<syncfusion:TimeSpanEdit Format="hh:mm" Value="{Binding SelectedTempSetpoint.Time, Mode=OneWay}" />
<syncfusion:UpDown Value="{Binding SelectedTempSetpoint.Value, Mode=OneWay}"  >
<Button  Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddTempSetpointCommand}">
```

I use the OneWay-Binding to update the content of the Edit-Control each Time or Value of the selected element in the datagrid changes. However i want to be able to change the values inside the edit controls and use that values to add another element to the datagrid. For that I want to use the Command Property of the Button (and a DelegateCommand in the ViewModel).
Typically i would bind the Value of the edit controls to properties in my VM but that way i would lose the funtionality that they update if the SelectedElement changes.
What would be the proper way to do that? Use separate Properties and update them in the VM? Or is there a way to bind the control to multiple properties?

Answer (score 0):

i was able to achieve this with new property in Model and MultiValueConverter,

code below,

```
  <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:CustomMultiConverter x:Key="CustomMultiConverter"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName}" />
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CustomMultiConverter}">
                <Binding Mode="OneWay" Path="SelectedName" />
                <Binding Mode="TwoWay" Path="NewName" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Content="Add" />
</StackPanel>



public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand addCommand;

    public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get { return addCommand; }
        set { addCommand = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> names;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Names
    {
        get { return names; }
        set { names = value; }
    }
    private string selectedName;
    private string newName;

    public string NewName
    {
        get { return newName; }
        set { newName = value; OnPropertyChanged("NewName"); }
    }

    public string SelectedName
    {
        get { return selectedName; }
        set { selectedName = value;OnPropertyChanged("SelectedName"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Names = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Names.Add("name1");
        Names.Add("name2");
        addCommand = new DelegateCommand(Add, CanAdd);
    }

    private bool CanAdd(object arg)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void Add(object obj)
    {
        Names.Add(NewName);
    }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class CustomMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(values != null)
        {
            if (values[0] != null)
                return values[0];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var obj = new object[2];
        obj[0] = null;
        obj[1] = value;
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Please correct me if anything is wrong.